# VMWare: About snapshots: do they usually occupy how much% of the disk space source VM? And are they used to downgrade software?

Tags: vmware, snapshot, samba

I would like to update the samba on a 3TB NAS. My boss suggested making a clone, however, there is no storage that will fit him whole. If a snapshot of the VM costs a smaller size, and serves to, in case of failure, restore the samba as it was, making it a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real guide on how much space snapshots occupy. That will greatly depend on the activity on the VM where the snapshot has been taken. If it's an active VM (database or something of the like), there could be a considerable amount of data written. If it's not a very used VM, there could be limited to no data written to the backend datastore.